# What is the meaning of start-dev?

Tags: docker

I have command

```bash
docker run --name vy-keycloak -p 8085:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:22.0.3 start-dev
```

It runs success. What is the meaning of `start-dev`?

Related https://www.keycloak.org/server/all-config

https://www.keycloak.org/getting-started/getting-started-docker#_start_keycloak

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`start-dev` is the command which is starting when the container is running.

In the documentation (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) you see that the `docker run` command is defined like this:

```
docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

After the image name (in your case it's `quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:22.0.3`) you can call a command. In your case it's `start-dev`.